# How to understand intuitively the geometry of a pantograph

Tags: geometry

I have built a pantograph, driven by a pair of small motors - I hope the arrangement is clear enough to understand:

[image: Pantograph diagram]

[image: Pantograph photo]

In my software to drive the machine, I can handle the geometry very nicely now; it's able to ascertain all kinds of properties of the system and adjust for them appropriately.

However, despite having successfully built the machine and written the software, I still find that I have a poor *intuitive* understanding of the pantograph. I can calculate the effect of any change in the geometry, such as the length of an arm, but I often find out that what I intuited it would be is quite off the mark.

How can I understand it better on this basis?

I mean things being able to intuit basic rules such as:

- if all arms are made longer, then the drawing area will be larger
- the closer together the motors, the larger the drawing area and the less waste of movement
- if the driving arms (the ones attached to the motors) are shorter than the following arms (the ones attached to the pen) the greater the mechanical advantage the motors will have (i.e. there's a reduction gear effect) and the greater the rotation of the motors for a given drawing area

I'm also interested in being able to correct for distortions caused by mechanical imperfections in the system (such as non-linearities in the motors) by tweaking small aspects of the calculations, but with an inadequate intuitive picture of the geometric relationships it's very hard to do.

How can I think about the pantograph to get a better mental picture of it?